# Unable to upload files to server with socket connection (_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'E'.)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using Python 3.7 and tkinter to develop this program. This program work as a file uploader to server through a socket connection. But the problem is when I upload a files it will show "upload completed" but the server didn't receive any of it. After the upload complete, an error will be show when I clicked on refresh button (the `ListboxContentrefresh` function is to refresh the listbox content of the server.) Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here ? Thanks

**Error message:**

```
line 274, in ListboxContentrefresh
    arr = pickle.loads(s.recv(1024))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'E'.
```

**Image of my program:**
[image]

**Client code:**

```
def ListboxContentrefresh():
    #==========Listbox================
    # THE ITEMS INSERTED WITH A LOOP
    s.send(('flist~s').encode("utf-8"))
    arr = pickle.loads(s.recv(1024))
    listbox.delete(0, END)  # clear listbox
    for i in arr:
        listbox.insert(END, i)
    
    def mouseHover(event):
        global x
        x = listbox.curselection()[0]
        file = listbox.get(x)

        ext = (".txt", ".csv")
        if file.endswith(ext):
            s.send(("fdown~" + file).encode("utf-8"))  # must have
            data = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
                filesize = data[6:]
                s.send("OK".encode("utf-8"))
                f = open(file, 'wb')  # must have
                data = (s.recv(1024))
                totalRecv = len(data)
                f.write(data)
                while int(totalRecv) < int(filesize):
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    totalRecv += len(data)
                    f.write(data)

                    sys.stdout.write("\r|" + "█" * int((totalRecv / float(filesize)) * 50) + "|{0:.2f}".format(
                        (totalRecv / float(filesize)) * 100) + "%  ")
                    sys.stdout.flush()

                    time.sleep(0.01)
                print("\nDownload Complete!")
                f.close()
                global data2
                data2 = open(file).read().splitlines()

                joined_string = "\n".join(data2)
                text.delete("1.0", END)

                text.insert(END, joined_string)

        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("WARNING", "Currently only .txt/csv file is supported.")

    listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", mouseHover)

def uploadfiletoserver():
    try:
        # open file selector
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="/", title='Please select a directory')

        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            s.send(str("fup~" + filename).encode("utf-8"))
            s.send(str.encode("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename))))
            filesize = int(os.path.getsize(filename))
            userResponse = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    s.send(bytesToSend)
                    totalSend = len(bytesToSend)
                    while int(totalSend) < int(filesize):
                        bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                        totalSend += len(bytesToSend)
                        s.send(bytesToSend)
                        sys.stdout.write("\r|" + "█" * int((totalSend / float(filesize)) * 50) + "|{0:.2f}".format(
                            (totalSend / float(filesize)) * 100) + "%  ")
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                    print("\nUpload Completed!")
        else:
            print("File Does Not Exist!")
    except:
        raise
```

**Server code:**

```
import socket, os, subprocess, shutil, pickle, struct, threading
## gettig the hostname by socket.gethostname() method
hostname = socket.gethostname()
## getting the IP address using socket.gethostbyname() method
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

# Create a Socket ( connect two computers)

def create_socket():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ""
        port = 9999
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        create_socket()


# Binding the socket and listening for connections
def bind_socket():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(5)
        ## printing the hostname and ip_address
        print(f"Hostname: {hostname}")
        print(f"IP Address: {ip_address}")
        print(f"Running Port: {port}")
    except socket.error as msg:
        bind_socket()
        print(bind_socket())


# send file list

def flist(conn):
    try:
        arr = pickle.dumps(os.listdir())
        conn.send(arr)
        print(arr)
    except:
        conn.send(('Error').encode("utf-8"))


# accept file from server

def fdown(filename, conn):
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
            filesize = data[6:]
            conn.send("OK".encode("utf-8"))
            f = open(filename, 'wb')
            data = (conn.recv(1024))
            totalRecv = len(data)
            f.write(data)
            while int(totalRecv) < int(filesize):
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                totalRecv += len(data)
                f.write(data)
            f.close()
    except:
        conn.send(('Error').encode("utf-8"))


# send file

def fup(filename, conn):

    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        conn.send(str.encode("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename))))
        filesize = int(os.path.getsize(filename))
        userResponse = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                conn.send(bytesToSend)
                totalSend = len(bytesToSend)
                while int(totalSend) < int(filesize):
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    totalSend += len(bytesToSend)
                    conn.send(bytesToSend)
    else:
        conn.send("ERROR".encode("utf-8"))



# main
def main(s):
    while True:
        data = (s.recv(1024)).decode("utf-8").split('~')
        if data[0] == 'fdown':
            fup(data[1], s)
        elif data[0] == 'fup':
            fdown(data[1], s)
        elif data[0] == 'flist':
            flist(s)
        else:
            s.send(".".encode('utf-8'))


def socket_accept():
    while True:
        conn, address = s.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target=main, args=(conn,))
        t.start()


create_socket()
bind_socket()
socket_accept()
```

Comment: why do you pickle your data?

Comment: Because i want to send and receive data from server and client

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's probably an error in your flist function.  Try changing the client to:

```
def ListboxContentrefresh():
    #==========Listbox================
    # THE ITEMS INSERTED WITH A LOOP
    s.send(('flist~s').encode("utf-8"))
    arr = s.recv(1024)
    if arr == b'Error':
        messagebox.showinfo("ERROR", "Error received from flist!")
        return
    arr = pickle.loads(arr)
    ...
```

This should show you if there is an error on the client-side.  And if you'd like you can change the server-side to help diagnose the issue:

```
def flist(conn):
    try:
        arr = pickle.dumps(os.listdir())
        conn.send(arr)
        print(arr)
    except Exception as e:
        conn.send(('Error').encode("utf-8"))
        print("Exception: ", e)
```

Comment: After i paste your code to my server and client, it show me the error message when i click on refresh. it couldn't let me refresh the listbox. But the flist work when i not upload any files, i could view every files with no issues